# Need to navigate to the second tab of a page using JS tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So at the moment I have a page which uses two tabs, each tab is display none until the associated tab button at the top is clicked. I'm usin jquery for the click event.
At the moment let's say tab 1 is the default, I need to navigate to tab 2 from another page.

I was wondering if I could add something to the link on the other page which would act as a click on the tab button.

Any way, really need some help on this

Comment: you can find the div id and load the page/navigate the content. `$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});` instead of alert you can render your functionality. #target is an example id of div.

Comment: The code you've posted just seems to be a jquery onclick. How can I use this from another page?

Comment: Is your tab some UI control or div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.hash == "#tab2"){
    $(".tab-label-2").click();
}
});
```

Putting the above into the page with the tabs on. Add #tab2 to the end of the link you're clicking on

window.location.hash checks anything from the #. if it's the same it will run the function which in the above case is clicking on something